# is there a way to have the compiler warn/err if an attribute section is not defined in the linker script?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm

Using arm-none-eabi-gcc compiler toolchain for arm microcontrollers, and am defining a specific section in `FLASH` where this `foo` variable should live.

Let's say I have the example definition:

```
int foo __attribute__((section(".bar"))) = 5;
```

What I have observed is that if `.bar` is not assigned in the linker script, than the build will successfully succeed and `foo` will live in `RAM` instead as initialized data (the constant initial value will of course add to the `FLASH` size as well). The annoying part is, the linker does not complain when the section does not exist and so if expecting data to reside in `FLASH` it may silently live in a non-fixed location in `RAM`. Is there a compile/linker option to force a failure if this occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GNU ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options), ld can be told to handle orphan linker sections as errors using the `--orphan-handling=error` command-line option.

Assuming orphan.c does contain the following code:

```
int foo __attribute__((section(".bar"))) = 5;

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

The following command does succeed:

```
aarch64-elf-gcc   --specs=rdimon.specs  -o orphan orphan.c
```

But that one does fail:

```
aarch64-elf-gcc   --specs=rdimon.specs  -Wl,--orphan-handling=error -o orphan orphan.c
c:/git/cortex-baremetal/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-elf/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-elf/bin/ld.exe: error: unplaced orphan section `.tm_clone_table' from `c:/git/cortex-baremetal/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-elf/7.3.1/crtbegin.o'.
c:/git/cortex-baremetal/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-elf/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-elf/bin/ld.exe: error: unplaced orphan section `.bar' from `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc6aRct8.o'.
c:/git/cortex-baremetal/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-elf/7.3.1/../../../../aarch64-elf/bin/ld.exe: error: unplaced orphan section `.tm_clone_table' from `c:/git/cortex-baremetal/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-elf/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-elf/7.3.1/crtend.o'.
```

It seems the default linker script I used for the purpose of this example is missing another section, `'.tm_clone_table'`. It would have to be fixed in order not to trigger an error when `'.bar'` section is properly defined.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like `--orphan-handling=error` is not supported in `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, though...

Comment: This may not be supported by the compiler you are using - you did not mention where it does come from, nor its version - but I observed the same behavior with the gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_arm-eabi Linaro toolchain a couple of minutes ago. Just give it a try, it is available here, along with the i686/x86_64 Linux versions: https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-eabi/

Comment: unfortunately changing compilers is not an option at this point, and trying it with our compiler results in an unknown compiler flag error :/

Comment: In this case, you don't need to change compiler. You need either to 1) change linker and use it for production 2) use a recent linker in your build process for for the only purpose of triggering an error in the case a section would be missing. That is, you would first  link your .o/.a first with your current linker into a production executable, then using a recent one for linking a validation executable that would not be used for production. This probably be preferable to risking a variable to be put in a default section without any warning/error.